# Al comparar dos variables numericas no reconoce cual es el valor mayor, por qué?

Tags: variables

Tengo una tabla donde muestra las facturas pendientes de pago por cliente, con su respectiva fecha de emision y su saldo al cancelar, en esta tabla, muestra un checkbox, cuya funcion es al clickear tomará el valor de la factura y lo considerará como pago, el detalle es que quiero ir descontando de un monto digitado en textbox type="number", pero al realizar la comparacion si el saldo del documento es menor al disponible lo toma como si fuera mayor o viceversa. Este codigo se genera en un archivo .js
Podrian ayudarme por favor.

```js
{
       disponible = $('#dispopago').val(); //disponible = 12000

   $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
       montopago = $(this).val();                     // montopago = 9172.64
       numdoc = $(this).attr("at-pago");              // abc
   });
   if(montopago > disponible) {               //se cumple si montopago es menor, aun colocando el signo >
       alert('pago si es menor a disponible');
       valpago = montopago;
   }else if(montopago == disponible){
       alert('valor del pago es igual al disponible');
       valpago = disponible;
   else if(montopago < disponible){
       alert('valor del pago sera abono');
       valpago = disponible;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando obtienes un valor de un elemento con `.val()`, siempre será una `string`, lo que tendrías que hacer es transformar tus valores a numéricos para poder compararlos.

En este caso

```
disponible = parseFloat($('#dispopago').val());
```

y

```
montopago = parseFloat($(this).val());
```

Usamos el `parseFloat()` ya que tus valores manejan decimales pero hay otras funciones dependiendo del tipo de dato que quieras transformar.

Comment: Gracias, al colocar el parseFloat() como lo sugeriste, el valor del monto pago pasa a ser CERO y el disponible solo 12000

Comment: @FranciscoVillalta eso puede suceder por algún otro detalle en los elementos de tus documentos. En este caso puedes editar la pregunta para incluir el HTML con que estás trabajando para darnos un panorama mas amplio de tu detalle. En un caso simple el checkbox espera tener el parámetro value y que este sea numérico  `<input type="checkbox" name="montopago" value="9172.64"> 9172.64`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Abraham, tenia problemas con unas variables que habia declarado antes con los mismos nombres en otra funcion y eso me daba problema, al tomar el valor del this, si colocaba el parseFloat, daba error, lo hice al momento de comparar los valores de las variables y ahora me funcionó. Muchas Gracias.